# Sorting ListView Items for 1 column as integer?

Tags: c#, listview, sorting, visual-studio-2012

I want to sort one column in my ListView as an integer, because if i want to sort them i get the result.

If i try to sort them i just get this. I think the reason is, that they are compared as strings?

1 
10
11 
12 
2 
20 
21 
3

I want them to be sorted like this:

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
10
11
20

and so on ...

This is my class to compare the items:

```
public class ItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Column { get; set; }

    public SortOrder Order { get; set; }

    public ItemComparer(int colIndex)
    {
        Column = colIndex;
        Order = SortOrder.None;
    }
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        int result;

        ListViewItem itemA = a as ListViewItem;
        ListViewItem itemB = b as ListViewItem;

        result = String.Compare(itemA.SubItems[Column].Text, itemB.SubItems[Column].Text);

        if (Order == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            result *= -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

in Form:

```
ItemComparer sorter = listView_Data.ListViewItemSorter as ItemComparer;

if(sorter == null)
{
    sorter = new ItemComparer(e.Column);
    sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
    listView_Data.ListViewItemSorter = sorter;
}
if(e.Column == sorter.Column)
{
    if(sorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        sorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
    }
    else
    {
        sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }
}
else
{
    sorter.Column = e.Column;
    sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
listView_Data.Sort();
```

How can i add for column 1, where the id from the database is a integer sort, so that they are sorted like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = String.Compare(itemA.SubItems[Column].Text, itemB.SubItems[Column].Text);
```

Why not just use the values directly, if they are indeed just integers?

```
result = Int32.Parse(itemA.SubItems[Column].Text) - Int32.Parse(itemB.SubItems[Column].Text);
```

You may need some additional logic to check the columns so that you're not trying to parse integers from columns containing words though.

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it so that others with similar issues can find the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: i will do that, thanks for your Answer and your help but i have one more Problem, if you could help me again i'd really appreciate that.  I have on column in my ListView, which contains alphabetical charachters and numbers, what can i do then, if i want them to be sorted like 1a, 1b, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 11a and so on?

Comment: Separate the numerical and alphabetical components. Do a comparison just on the number part first, then if (and only if) the numerical compare equals 0 (meaning the same, like 2a and 2b would be), do another compare on the alphabetical component, like you had it before.   You can just replace the 0 result with the alphabetical result in that case. a - b = -1 , having the effect of 2a being less than 2b, which is what you want.  Your ascending/descending factor would still work as-is.

Comment: How do i do these split for each number. The number or the length is not always the same. I tried to split like these but how can i add each number to these i tried \b but it is not working.                               itemA.SubItems[4].Text.Split('\d');
itemB.SubItems[4].Text.Split('\d');
result = Int32.Parse(itemA.SubItems[Column].Text) - Int32.Parse(itemB.SubItems[Column].Text);                            Like this you mean or?

Comment: Dont use `String.Split()` unless you have an explicit delimiter, because it will return an array with that character excluded.  Instead use something like:  

`new string(input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());`
will give you your numbers, and just invert `IsDigit` to get your non-number characters.

Comment: I've got it now ;)                                               Thank you very much for your help, time and support.